# React Eslint - Dispatch no longer needed as dependency?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

So far, I thought that if you have a `dispatch` function created by `useReducer` and want to use this in a `useEffect`, the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` linting rule wants you to include that `dispatch` function in a dependency array.

Since dispatch has a stable identity, this is a safe pattern and even [Gaearon](https://github.com/gaearon) termed this as "intentional" (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18396#issuecomment-606063301)).

Now, I am surprised that in my latest project ESLint actually does *not* complain about omitting `dispatch` from the dependency array.

I have reproduced this in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-currying-buvtk8?file=/src/App.tsx). As you can see (under the "Problems" tab) the first `useEffect` has a missing dependency according to ESLint while the second does not:

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  function printCount() {
    console.log(count);
  }

  // As expected, eslint complains about missing dependency
  React.useEffect(() => {
    printCount();
  }, []);

  const [, dispatchPrint] = React.useReducer(printCount, undefined);

  // Why is eslint fine with omitting dispatchPrint here? 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatchPrint();
  }, []);

  return (
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  );
}
```

From my understanding this linting behaviour would also be ok, since `dispatch` is stable, and it could be considered OK to not list it as dependency.

But is this actually the intended linting behavior and is this documented somewhere? Why is this not linted in my example even if Gaearon tells us that it is "intended" to lint this.

To make it clear, I'm not asking about whether or not I should include `dispatch` as a dependency or how to adjust my code to fulfil or ignore certain linting rules. I want to clarify my confusion why the linter isn't complaining even though I'm reading everywhere that it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the code for `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/fc90eb636876d54d99ace2773dd4923f3e848106/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L151-L164), it knows `useReducer`'s `dispatch` to be stable:

```
      // const [state, dispatch] = useReducer() / React.useReducer()
      //               ^^^ true for this reference
```

So yes, based on the code and comment for the linter, it is the intended behavior, and it shouldn't complain.